# Commerce Line Item Taxonomy Reference Filtered by Product Selection

Tags: 7, commerce, taxonomy-terms, views

Here's the scenario:

- I'm selling furniture. I have a chair we'll call Mission Chair.
- The Mission Chair comes in oak or maple, both are priced differently. I have a field in my product
- I have a product display created which references these 2 products
- Customers need to choose 1 of 5 stain colors, but each type of wood has 5 different choices (and they're not the same choices)
- The stain choice is required, but does not affect the price.

In my Product Variation Type, I have a term reference field which is referencing a Wood Species vocabulary.

I assume I would create a term reference field on the line item type where they would make the stain color choice. What I need to figure out is how do I do some kind of contextual filter to only show the stains available for the chosen wood species? (which is a taxonomy term on the chosen product - not the display, the product variation)

Should the stains be child terms in the same vocabulary as the wood species, or should it be a separate vocabulary with an additional term field that references a specific wood species (taxonomy reference, the same vocabulary the product variation uses) for each stain color term, and then filter on that somehow?

Comment: Are you trying to use the standard Commerce Add to Car form (which has support for multiple attributes, and some limitations) or did you come up with a custom add to cart form?

Comment: The standard Add to Cart form - just need to figure out how to do some kind of contextual filter - maybe using a views field on the line item type so I can do a contextual filter?

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic approaches you can use: either treat the stain color as a customization or treat it as a second attribute.  Which you pick depends on a little on your backend process needs and the experience you want to provide.

If you use a second attribute and have a product variation for each stain in each wood, Commerce's default add to cart form should provide the user experience you are describing. You might find it helpful to take a [look at this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8wUo7r9a-I).

If you want to treat stain as a customization you'll likely want a couple extra modules -- in particular [Commerce Customizable Product](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product).  Commerce Guys have a [tutorial covering that scenario](https://drupalcommerce.org/videos/tutorials/customizable-products-pizza-store).

Comment: Trying to avoid creating product variations for this - I have enough other variations to worry about which I didn't mention :-)

Comment: Than you'll want to treat them as product customizations (which probably makes some sense).

Comment: I found this thread (https://www.drupal.org/node/1873396) which probably describes a situation somewhat similar to mine. I don't need to adjust the price based on the stain color - I just need some way of triggering a filter of the line item taxonomy reference field (or views field which would be a list of filtered taxonomy terms) based on a chosen term from the product variation - does that make sense?